# apt-cache policy apt = phased 20%, meaning?

Tags: linux-mint, apt, upgrade

After upgrading to Linux Mint 21, I am puzzled by some held back packages, one of which is `apt`:

```
# apt-cache policy apt

apt:
  Installed: 2.4.6
  Candidate: 2.4.7
  Version table:
     2.4.7 500 (phased 20%)
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.4.6 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.4.5 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

Could anyone elaborate, thank you?

---

`apt-get upgrade` trial below:

```
# apt-get upgrade

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  apt apt-transport-https apt-utils cryptsetup cryptsetup-bin cryptsetup-initramfs
  cryptsetup-run libapt-pkg6.0 libcryptsetup12
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Phased updates are updates which should only be applied by a subset of all systems running a given release of a distribution; this allows updates to be rolled out progressively.

This feature was introduced by [this commit](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/commit/c5bc86d45e003905ef411146e66b414d26fb1ff8) and is documented as follows:

> #### Phased Updates
>
> APT understands a field called `Phased-Update-Percentage`
> which can be used to control the rollout of a new version. It is an integer between 0 and 100.
>
> A system's eligibility to a phased update is determined by seeding
> random number generator with the package source name, the version number,
> and `/etc/machine-id`, and then calculating an integer in the range [0, 100].
> If this integer is larger than the `Phased-Update-Percentage`,
> the version is pinned to 1, and thus held back. Otherwise, normal policy rules apply.
>
> In case you have multiple systems that you want to receive the same set of updates, you can set
> `APT::Machine-ID` to a UUID such that they all phase the same, or set `APT::Get::Never-Include-Phased-Updates`
> or `APT::Get::Always-Include-Phased-Updates` to true such that APT will never/always consider phased updates.

The percentage is controlled by the repository owner. [Ubuntu phased updates can be tracked here](https://ubuntu-archive-team.ubuntu.com/phased-updates.html).